# Consecutive position measurement yield arbitrary fast movement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity

Suppose we got a particle inside a long tube, and two observers Alice and Bob situated at two very distant points of the tube. Alice performs a measurement on the position (checks whether it is in front of her), then a measurement of the momentum (or any other that doesn't commute with position), then Bob does a measurement of the position (whether particle is in front of him).

There is a non null probability that Alice and Bob both find the particle in front of them when they measure the position. In fact, we can make the probability arbitrary high with the right choice of the second measurement ( an orthonormal basis with >1/2 scalar product with the dirac function in Bob's position).

However, the process can be done arbitrary quickly (Bob and Alice's times can be precisely synchronised and only the measurements instrument speed will matter), but the distance arbitrarily big, implying a non zero possibility of a faster than light speed.

How is this explained in physics ? Is there an oversimplified hypothesis I shouldn't have assumed ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot measure a momentum of a particle with an arbitrary precision if you only have access to a limited region of the space (even if you've confirmed earlier that your particle is indeed in this region of space). And measuring momentum using only local data (from your own region of space) will not cause the position to become so undetermined that the particle can be detected by a far away observer.

Careful analysis in relativistic quantum mechanincs shows that a particle once detected in one specific region of spacetime cannot be ever detected in another spacially-separated region of spacetime, no matter what other measurments or operations you perform on it. In other words, even quantum particles cannot teleport faster than light speed.

Answer (score 0):

Alice cannot prepare a delta function of position at bob's location by measuring momentum at a different location. The more precise is the momentum measurement, the more spread the position will be in the new state. If you measure momentum with less precision, say a Gaussian packet,  you will also get a position Gaussian packet, but centered at the measurement site. If you could create delta states in position at will at any arbitrary distance by performing a measurement, then you could transmit information faster than light. Just create a device with two positions representing two bits.